# Send Statuses to Github

Tags: bash, github

I'm trying to send a new status to an PR, I follow that steps:

1.- I made a call to the API to obtain the STATUSES_URL whith a command like:

```
curl -X GET -u *MY_TOKEN_ID*:x-oauth-basic 'https://api.github.com/repos/*MY_ORGANIZATION*/*MY_REPO*/pulls/18'
```

2.- Into the Json file result I finded the STATUSES_URL field with the URL that I need to use, a URL like:

```
"statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/*MY_ORGANIZATION*/*MY_REPO*/statuses/*MY_COMMIT_ID*",
```

3.- then, I launched a request to the API with the STATUSES_URL like this:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" -d @statuses.json -u *MY_TOKEN_ID*:x-oauth-basic https://api.github.com/repos/*MY_ORGANIZATION*/*MY_REPO*/statuses/*MY_COMMIT_ID*
```

Content for json file:

```
{ 
   "state": "success", 
   "target_url": "https://*MY.CI.SERVER*/job/*XXXXX*/job/*REPO*/view/change-requests/job/PR-18/1/console",
   "description": "Jenkins-CI",
   "context": "continuous-integration/jenkins"
}
```

But allways obtain the same results: Not Found

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/#create-a-status"
}
```

I readed all documentation about the statuses's procedure but I can't understant what it's my fail.

Any sugestions?